# Simple Cache Mechanism

Tags: c#

I have this simple cache mechanism for a repeated task in service. It uses static variable to store the information. Please suggest on how is it and if it could be better.

Premise: I need to verify transaction from stores. There can be lots of transactions happening repeatedly from multiple stores. Thus, this simple cache manager for getting the store information. I want it to be simple yet effective and fast.

**StoreCacheManager.cs**

```
public class StoreCacheManager
{
    private static List<StoreCacheInformation> _merchantStores = new List<StoreCacheInformation>();
    private DBEntities _db;
    private TimeSpan _cacheTime = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);//1 Hour
    public TimeSpan CacheTimeSpan { get { return _cacheTime; } }
    public StoreCacheManager(DBEntities db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<StoreCacheInformation> Get(int storeId)
    {
        if (_merchantStores.Any())
        {
            var store =
                _merchantStores.FirstOrDefault(i => i.StoreID == storeId);
            if (store != null)
            {
                // Check if Cache time has expired
                if (store.CacheDateTimeUtc.Add(_cacheTime) < DateTime.UtcNow)
                {
                    lock (_merchantStores)
                    {
                        _merchantStores.Remove(store);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return store;
                }
            }
        }
        return await GetAndCache(storeId);
    }

    private async Task<StoreCacheInformation> GetAndCache(int storeId)
    {
        var store = await GetStoreInfo(storeId);
        if (store != null)
        {
            lock (_merchantStores)
            {
                _merchantStores.Add(store);
            }
        }
        return store;
    }
    private async Task<StoreCacheInformation> GetStoreInfo(int storeId)
    {
        var storeInfo = await _db.Stores.Where(i => i.StoreID == storeId).Select(i => new StoreCacheInformation()
        {
            CountryCode = i.CountryObj.CountryCode,
            MerchantID = i.VendorOrgID ?? 0,
            TelephoneCode = i.CountryObj.TelephoneCountryCode,
            StoreID = storeId,
            //todo: deviceId and Token

        }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (storeInfo != null)
        {
            storeInfo.CacheDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
        return storeInfo;
    }
}
```

**StoreCacheInformation.cs**

```
public class StoreCacheInformation
{
    public int MerchantID { get; set; }
    public int StoreID { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime CacheDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string AuthToken { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `ConcurrentDictionary` be better for this purpose?

Comment: i actually never heard of it :P i will look it up

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: Use `MemoryCache` - it's a .NET built in, just build a short wrapper around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Concurrency**

If you want to implement it thread-safe, you have also lock the whole transaction. For instance: `store != null` assumes that there is no item in cache. Imagine that after that check another thread added one. That would result in a cache where the same item is cached twice.

Conside to use a thread-safe collection (e.g. [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx)) instead of using locking.

.Net Framework already provides a thread-safe cache: [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx).

I am not very familiar with the entity framework, but as far as I know is the [DbContext not thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126616/is-dbcontext-thread-safe). Therefore it is not a good idea to use a single instance of it in multithreaded environments.

---

**Code Style**

- `_merchantStores`, `_db` and `_cacheTime` should be read-only.
- Methods that return a `Task` should be called xxx**Async**
- The property setter in `StoreCacheInformation` should be private or at least internal. Otherview external code may modify the state of the cached items.
- For many cached items, it is better to use a dictionary instead of list.

Comment: The DbContext is single instace per cache manager. I intend the scope of cache manager to be per request. I will look up the ConcurrentDictionary though.

Comment: @Ruchan: Ok, than it is OK. I didn't know that it is an ASP.Net application.... In case that you don't want to use in the build-in cache (There is also one for ASP.Net), I added few additional points regaring to code style.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the code with your suggestions. Also could you suggest a way to clear expired items?

Comment: @Ruchan: Please do not edit your question. Otherwise the answers are not valid anymore. If you want to show the refactored version, you could add it as answer or post a new question if you want to get a review again.

Comment: _Also could you suggest a way to clear expired items?_ Actually I would use one of the build-in caches, because they handle that kind of problem. If you want to implement your own solution you have to ask another one because I am not an ASP.Net developer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Update

StoreCacheManager.cs

```
public class StoreCacheManager
{
    //private static List<StoreCacheInformation> _merchantStores = new List<StoreCacheInformation>();
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, StoreCacheInformation> _merchantStores =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<int, StoreCacheInformation>();
    private readonly DBEntities _db;
    private readonly TimeSpan _cacheTime = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);//1 Hour
    public TimeSpan CacheTimeSpan { get { return _cacheTime; } }
    public StoreCacheManager(DBEntities db)
    {
        _db = db;

        var x = new System.Web.Caching.Cache();

    }

    public StoreCacheInformation Get(int storeId)
    {
        lock (_merchantStores)
        {
            if (_merchantStores.Any())
            {
                var store =
                    _merchantStores.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Key == storeId);
                if (store.Value != null)
                {
                    // Check if Cache time has expired
                    if (store.Value.CacheDateTimeUtc.Add(_cacheTime) < DateTime.UtcNow)
                    {
                       _merchantStores.Remove(storeId);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return store.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
            return GetAndCache(storeId);
        }
    }

    private StoreCacheInformation GetAndCache(int storeId)
    {
        var store = GetStoreInfo(storeId);
        if (store != null)
        {
            _merchantStores.TryAdd(storeId, store);
        }
        return store;
    }
    private StoreCacheInformation GetStoreInfo(int storeId)
    {
        var storeInfo = _db.Stores.Where(i => i.StoreID == storeId).Select(i => new StoreCacheInformation()
        {
            CountryCode = i.CountryObj.CountryCode,
            MerchantID = i.VendorOrgID ?? 0,
            TelephoneCode = i.CountryObj.TelephoneCountryCode,
            StoreID = storeId,
            //todo: deviceId and Token

        }).FirstOrDefault();
        if (storeInfo != null)
        {
            storeInfo.CacheDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
        return storeInfo;
    }
}
```

Changes

- added lock to the whole transaction. The async tasks had to go since it gives error like "await" can't be used with try...catch, lock
- made properties readonly.
- added extension to Remove method

Comment: You could also use `TimeSpan.FromHours(1)` to get rid of the comment ;)

Comment: If you are making changes based on the review. You should consider making your answer a wiki answer IMHO.